# Pushing data from one View to another

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a table list of promotions held in an NSSet which I load into an array for the purpose of displaying the title/name on the cell. However I want to use the didselectrow method to push the selected promotion onto an individual promotion page. I've making `promo.featuredArray = self.featuredArray` however it doesn't seem to be passing the data. My code is as follows.

Promo list.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = featured.details;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.place.name;
    return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Promo * promo= [[Promo alloc] initWithNibName:@"Promo" bundle:nil];
    //Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    promo.featuredArray = self.featuredArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:promo animated:YES];
    [promo release];
    //[featured release];
}
```

Promo.m

```
@synthesize featuredArray, featured = __featured;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        self.clearImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_icon.png"];
        self.clearImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_icon_sel.png"];
        Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray init];
        self.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.name];
        self.time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.time];
        // self.description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.description];
        self.placeName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.Place];

        [super viewDidLoad];


        if([__featured.imageURL hasPrefix:@"http"])
        {
            [self getImageForPlace];
        }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        [self refreshImage];  
    //    }
    //    
        self.title = @"Promotion";

        UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_texture.png"]];
        self.view.backgroundColor = background;
        [background release];
        [featured release];
    }
```

Comment: Whats the object you want to pass to other view ?

Comment: woah what is this: `Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray init];`

Comment: should get into the habit of using props too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably this line:

```
Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray init];
```

This is wrong in many ways.

Making this a community wiki because I don't have time to write a full answer.

Comment: I don't understand this previous answer as I'm only new to stack over flow. I have tried pushing the position of the array in an int and using this to extract the data from the array:Featured*featured = [self.featuredArray objectAtIndex:self.position];
    

    self.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.name];
    self.time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.time];
    // self.description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.description];
    self.placeName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", __featured.Place];

Comment: Mike is right, this is like wearing a t-shirt backwards and inside out at the same time. you are basically init'ing that (already init'ed) and setting the pointer of the array to your featured object.